# How to configure user functions in DataStream programs?

Tags: apache-flink

I created a streaming environment with a configuration and tried to access this configuration in the `open()` method of a `RichMapFunction`.

Example:

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.setBoolean("a", true);
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = 
        StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(8, conf);

    DataStreamSource<Integer> source = env.fromElements(5,5,5,5,5);
    source.map(new RichMapFunction<Integer, Integer>() {

        @Override
        public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
            boolean a = parameters.getBoolean("a", false);
            super.open(parameters);
        }

        @Override
        public Integer map(Integer value) throws Exception {
            return value;
        }
    }).print();

    env.execute();
```

However, when debugging the `open()` method I find that the configuration is empty.

What am I doing wrong? How do I pass a configuration properly to a `RichFunction` in a streaming environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flink's DataStream and DataSet API share the same user function interfaces like `RichMapFunction` in your example.

The `Configuration` parameter of the `open` method of Flink's `RichFunction` is a legacy from the first versions of the DataSet API and not used in DataStream API. Flink serializes the object, that you provide in the `map()` call and ships it to the parallel workers. Hence, you can set parameters directly in the object as regular fields.

Comment: You might want to consider updating the documentation with this information.  All of the latest documentation shows a `withParameters` method being available but it's no where to be found. https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/best_practices.html

Comment: Yes, good point. It has already been updated for the next version (1.4) https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/best_practices.html. Not sure why the fix wasn't backported to the 1.3 branch.